# Backgroundtask for PushNotifications looses his trigger

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

1. First I had a background task registered for PushNotificationTrigger - no Problem here, I can find it in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks. But there is no activity on a pushnotification. And debugging tells me that the registered task has no trigger - although I registered it with the PushNotificationTrigger. Is there something I missed?

   ```
   private BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskName, IBackgroundTrigger connectedTrigger)
   {
       bool taskRegistered = false;
       BackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundTask = null;

       foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
       {
           if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
           {
               taskRegistered = true;
               backgroundTask = (BackgroundTaskRegistration)task.Value;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (!taskRegistered)
       {
           var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

           builder.Name = taskName;
           builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskName;
           builder.SetTrigger(connectedTrigger);
           backgroundTask = builder.Register();
           backgroundTask.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
           backgroundTask.Progress += new BackgroundTaskProgressEventHandler(BackgroundTask_Progress);
       }
       return backgroundTask;
   }

   async private void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       string toastVisual = "<visual><binding template='ToastGeneric'><text>Eine Testnachricht</text><text>OnCompleted has triggered</text></binding></visual>";
       string toastSound = "<audio src=\"ms-appx:///Sounds/blupp.wav\" loop=\"false\"/>";
       string toastXmlString = String.Format(@"<toast>{0}{1}</toast>", toastVisual, toastSound);

       XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
       toastXml.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

       var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

       DateTime expdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
       toast.ExpirationTime = expdate;

       ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   }

   private void BackgroundTask_Progress(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskProgressEventArgs args)
   {
       string toastVisual = "<visual><binding template='ToastGeneric'><text>Eine Testnachricht</text><text>OnProgress has triggered</text></binding></visual>";
       string toastSound = "<audio src=\"ms-appx:///Sounds/blupp.wav\" loop=\"false\"/>";
       string toastXmlString = String.Format(@"<toast>{0}{1}</toast>", toastVisual, toastSound);

       XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
       toastXml.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

       var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

       DateTime expdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
       toast.ExpirationTime = expdate;

       ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   }
   ```
2. Next I tried to solve with BackGround class. But with that solution I can't find any tasks registered. I guess I missed something to start, but can't figure out what.

   ```
   public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
   {
       BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BackgroundTasks here");

       var taskRegistered = false;
       var taskName = "alertPushNotification";

       foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
       {
           if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
           {
               taskRegistered = true;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (!taskRegistered)
       {
           var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

           builder.Name = taskName;
           builder.TaskEntryPoint = "RuntimeComponent1.ExampleBackgroundTask";
           builder.SetTrigger(new PushNotificationTrigger());
           BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
           task.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);
       }

       _deferral.Complete();
   }

   private void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
   {
       string toastVisual = "<visual><binding template='ToastGeneric'><text>Eine Testnachricht</text><text>OnCompleted has triggered</text></binding></visual>";
       string toastSound = "<audio src=\"ms-appx:///Sounds/blupp.wav\" loop=\"false\"/>";
       string toastXmlString = String.Format(@"<toast>{0}{1}</toast>", toastVisual, toastSound);

       XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
       toastXml.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

       var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

       DateTime expdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
       toast.ExpirationTime = expdate;

       ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   }

   private void OnProgress(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskProgressEventArgs args)
   {
       string toastVisual = "<visual><binding template='ToastGeneric'><text>Eine Testnachricht</text><text>OnProgress has triggered</text></binding></visual>";
       string toastSound = "<audio src=\"ms-appx:///Sounds/blupp.wav\" loop=\"false\"/>";
       string toastXmlString = String.Format(@"<toast>{0}{1}</toast>", toastVisual, toastSound);

       XmlDocument toastXml = new XmlDocument();
       toastXml.LoadXml(toastXmlString);

       var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

       DateTime expdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
       toast.ExpirationTime = expdate;

       ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   }
   ```

   }

Is there anyone who can give me a hint, what piece(s) of code I missed?

Comment: PushNotificationTrigger invokes a background work item on the app in response to the receipt of a raw notification. Are you receiving the Notification from cloud service?

Comment: Yes, I get it from Azure Webservices. I solved the Problem now. While registering the task, I used the same name for entrypoint and task. Switching the name to one different to entrypoint helped. Thank you :)